# Laravel - Query articles of a top category

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5.1

So i have categories, as an example, like this:

News (top category)

```
Sports (sub category)
World (sub category)
Local (sub category)
etc.
```

The articles all belong to some of the SUB CATEGORIES 
(but dont have a record of belonging to the top category in the pivot).

article_id 23 -> category_id 8 (its a many to many, with a pivot table)

The articles also have published_at, status, hits fields.

Now I need to:

```
get Articles
that belong to any of the sub categories of the Top News category,
where('status', 1),
where('published_at', '<=', Carbon::now()),
orderBy('published_at', 'desc'),
```

I not sure if I am clear enough, i hope its enough.

Any suggestions?

Comment: So if I understand correctly, there are three types of entities - `Category`, `Subcategory`, and `Article`, each modeled in a separate table?  There's a one-to-many relationship between a `Category` and its `Subcategory`s, and a many-to-many relationship between `Subcategory`s and `Article`s?

Have you implemented Eloquent models for each of these entities?

Comment: No. there is only category.php and article.php. category is in a relationship with itself, this way I can easily have 3 or more nested comments. I solved this issue but with a mysql view so it would be nice if there was a solution to grabbing these articles without a view.